# storage size of ‘names’ isn’t known

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

I get this error while compiling this .c source file

> /INIT_SOURCE_BUILD/src/names_list.c:7:
>   error: storage size of ‘names’ isn’t
>   known

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(){

    struct  List names;
    names->size = 3;

    struct ListElmt michael;
    struct ListElmt john;
    struct ListElmt adams;

    names->head = michael;

    michael->data = 12;
    michael->next = john;
    john->data = 14;
    john->next = adams;
    adams->data = 16;

    struct ListElmt pointer = List->head;
    for(int x = 0; x < 3 ; x++){
        printf("Iteration.%d data: %d", x, pointer->data);
        pointer->next = pointer->next->next;
    }
}
```

and here is header of this linked list

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include <stdio.h>

/*                                      Define linked list elements*/

typedef struct _ListElmt{

void                *data;
struct _ListElmt        *next;

} ListElmt;

/*                                      Define a structure for the list*/

typedef struct _List{

int                 size;
int                 (*match)(const void *key1, const void *key2);
void                (*destroy)(void *data);

ListElmt             *head;
ListElmt             *tail;

} List;

void list_init(List *list, void (*destroy)(void *data));

void list_destroy(List *list);

int list_ins_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, const void *data);

int list_rem_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, void **data);

int list_size(const List *list);

ListElmt *list_head(const List *list);

ListElmt *list_tail(const List *list);

int list_is_head(const ListElmt *element);

int list_is_tail(const ListElmt *element);

void *list_data(const ListElmt *element);

ListElmt *list_next(const ListElmt *element);
#endif
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you `typedef` a `struct` like that, you don't have to use `struct` when declaring it:

```
List names;
```

instead of

```
struct List names;
```

It's also not a pointer, so `names->size` should be `names.size`.

Comment: +1 Just a comment to make it clearer: the `struct List` does not exist. There is a `struct _List` and a typedef `List` that identifies the same type as `struct _List`. *(I hate typedefs!)*

Comment: i have another error names_list.c:14: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘List’)

Comment: @Sam: pointers take the `->` shortcut to access members, plain structs access them with `.`.

Comment: Another point: identifiers that begin with an underscore and capital letter (such as _List) are reserved for use by the implementation (7.1.3) and should not be used in application code.

Answer (score 3):

`struct List names;` doesn't declare a pointer, but you're trying to dereference it (using `->`).  Use `names.size` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The struct is called _List. The typedef is List. So you want

```
 List names;
```

or

```
struct _List names; /* probably not, the _ is convention for internal names */
```

Your line is declaring a "struct List" which isn't defined yet.

The other answers are quite correct about the . vs -> issue