# storage size of isn’t known using sigaltstack struct

Tags: c, linux, unix, struct

I'm using the sigalstack struct, details at:

[Here (MAC OSX)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html)

[HERE (LINUX)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html)

I'm just declaring it like so

```
struct sigaltstack aa;
```

and i keep getting the following error

```
error: storage size of ‘aa’ isn’t known
```

I read and checked [storage size of ‘names’ isn’t known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045550/storage-size-of-names-isnt-known) but I'm just declaring it, so it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use an uninitialized alternate stack like that. You have to allocate the space for the stack in its `ss_sp` field and set the corresponding size in its `ss_size` field.

The man7 link you linked has more information on this. In fact, it provides an example at the bottom of the page:

```
stack_t ss;

ss.ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
if (ss.ss_sp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;
ss.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
ss.ss_flags = 0;
if (sigaltstack(&ss, NULL) == -1)
    /* Handle error */;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to just run the mctx_create function in http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix2000/general/full_papers/engelschall/engelschall_html/ Which does  struct sigaltstack ss; 
    struct sigaltstack oss; so I'm not sure how that code works.

Comment: I'm not sure about that code, but you should be able to replace every occurence of `struct sigaltstack` with `struct stack_t`, just remember to `#include <signal.h>`; but as @JonathanLeffler pointed out, that code is old. It's possible you might encounter other issues as well.

Comment: What may have been OK in 2000 is no longer OK in 2013.  The systems have matured; the POSIX standard version has been around long enough that people are not expected to be using the pre-standard variant of `sigaltstack()` — and hence `struct sigaltstack` — any more.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mac OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html) page you link to says (in the section on 'Legacy Synopsis'):

> #### COMPATIBILITY
>
> Use of the (obsolete) `sigaltstack` struct will cause compiler diagnostics.  Use `stack_t`, defined in `<signal.h>`.

This suggests that you should not attempt to use `struct sigaltstack`.  The page also shows how you're expected to do it on Mac OS.  The Linux page also shows how you're supposed to use the `stack_t` type and makes no mention of `struct sigaltstack` at all.

Comment: It doesn't work any more; you've just demonstrated that.  As I noted in a comment to another answer, what may have been OK in 2000 is no longer OK in 2013. The systems have matured; the POSIX standard version has been around long enough that people are not expected to be using the pre-standard variant of `sigaltstack()` — and hence `struct sigaltstack` — any more.  So the sample code from Usenix 2000 is no longer valid.

Comment: Ok thank you, that was helpful. Any ideas on how to possibly port it over?

Comment: In `vim`:  `:/struct sigaltstack/s//stack_t/g`.  That's crude but probably effective, unless the Usenix code tries to do anything fancy.  The old interface had to take into account the direction that the stack grows; the modern interface does not.  So, you need to ensure that the updated Usenix code does not take into account the direction of stack growth.  I've not scrutinized the code to see what it does do.